# QWidget::mousePressEvent() on two widgets at once

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlabel, qmouseevent

I'm trying to run two `QWidget::mousePressEvent()` handlers at once. I have two widgets, A and B. 
B is inherited from `QLabel`, A from `QWidget`. I have overloaded `QWidget::mousePressEvent()` on both of them. Widget from B is getting `QPoint` cursor position and it's working.
A widget is getting this information from class B, but unfortunately, only if I click somewhere else outside the widget B (in blue area).
So what should I do to run `QWidget::mousePressEvent()` from widget A if I'm clicking on brown space from widget B?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `event->ignore()`, since A is behind B then presumably A is B's parent (maybe not direct but  that doesn't matter as long as it is down the tree), so if in the end of `B::mousePressEvent()` you `event->ignore()` then the event will continue propagating down and will trigger A's `mousePressEvent()` as well... eventually, if nothing else consumes the event down the path.

Also, since presumably the `mousePressEvent()` simply invokes some functionality, you could also manually do it from B's event handler for A, all you need is a reference to it, which is trivial to implement. You might have to map coordinates to the parent if they are relevant.

Comment: event->ignore() was exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot! (: